# Flash CS5 Actionscript 3.0 Go to Next Frame and Play Code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am coding a simple movie timeline in Flash CS5 actionscript 3.0. I have all my buttons working except for the Play button which I would like to code to say "go to next frame and play". Here is my current actionscript can anyone help me to find the correct code?

```
fastforwardBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(4025);
}

stop();

gotoStopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
}


gotoPlayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}

stopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}

playBtn.on (release) ;{
_root.gotoAndPlay(_currentframe+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_Click_Play);

function fl_Click_Play(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(root).play();
}
```

should work, if you have a simple fla. And if that doesn't seem to work, you may need something like this to target the right path:

```
MovieClip(this.parent).play();
```

Without knowing your fla structure, its just a guess ;)

also = _root is AS2, and always targets _level0. This is changed in AS3 to just "root", and targets the timeline of the topmost displayObjectContainer.

Comment: This works however it is just moving frame by frame every time I press the button. I would like to press it once and have it continually play through until the end.

Comment: instead of nextFrame(); use play();

Comment: Lol! play(). yes. For some odd reason I thought you were just trying to advance the movie 1 frame... /sigh. well = looks like you got what you were looking for. You might think about combining all these functions into a single function that tests for a unique parameter of the buttons themselves. You could do something as simple as assign them a name parameter that matches a label and then doing a switch statement on the target of the event. ( root.gotoAndPlay(e.target.name); )